# Get all controls implementing a certain directive inside a parent container

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I don't know if there's a way to do what I'm trying.
I have a big reactive form, splitted in different tabs. I can't break the form in sub-forms because the final rawValue is sent back to the API and must match the signature.

```
<form [formGroup]="driverGroup">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a [invalid]="main" id="main-tab" href="#main">Main data</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
         <a [invalid]="tab.code" [id]="tab.code + '-tab'" [href]="'#' + tab.code">tab.name</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div id="main">
      ...some controls here
   </div>
   <div [id]="tab.code" *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
      ...some other controls here
   </div>
</form>
```

I'd like each tab title to show in red if some control in the related form area is invalid. Ideally I want my `InvalidDirective` to search for all `FormControl` inside the container with the specified id and check for their `invalid` state to toggle its css class.

I don't know if this is an accepted practise in Angular 2+ and if there are better ways to to that...

Sample: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsa3k4)

My goal is to make the tab titles become red when the related "sub-form" contains an invalid control.

Comment: " I can't break the form in sub-forms because the final rawValue is sent back to the API and must match the signature". Your form shouldn't be coupled to the format that your API expects. You're allowed to map data from one format to another.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ideally you're right, but this form is totally dynamic and I have to adhere to some convention to bring data forth and back

Comment: So you must have some logic determining which controls receive the directive you're interested in. Can you not reuse that logic to query the source data? Can you provide a stackblitz that demonstrates your scenario?

Comment: It is not easy to guess problems based on a little snippet of code either... try to copy a sample response from your API and use that in the stackblitz instead of any api calls you may have.

Comment: @Alessandro Some dummy data with at least 2 form fields should be sufficient to demonstrate your environment - a complete working project isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the form group to that directive and determine if that is valid or invalid. then you can toggle your class.

Here, you have list of tabs. So, we can assume -

```
tabs[0] ==> FromArray.controls[0]
tabs[1] ==> FormArray.controls[1]
.................................
.................................
tabs[n] ==> FormArray.controls[n]
```

pass this info to your directive and toggle your color.

Here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsa3k4) . It works for the tabs.The tabs background color changing according to valid or invalid status of the form controls inside that tab.

For the main tab, some if else is needed. That is why I excluded that. Hopefully following the tabs solution, you can solve that case also.

Comment: It's not exactly like that, the example is simplified, but each tab contains a lot of form controls, that are not grouped into a FormGroup. Otherwise it would be easy...

Comment: I solved as the way you described in question and the stackblitz example code. It is impossible to know what your form look like if you don't state it clearly